# How does csrf_exempt works in django?

Tags: javascript, django, post, csrf, http-status-code-403

I have a server running on JavaScript trying to post username and password to another webpage running django. I understand that django requires you to include csrf tokens. i have control of both server and codes, what I wanted to achieve is instead of manually enter username and password, I wanted to post using JavaScript to django.

Let's say the django login page is "https://mayan/authentication/login/?next=/", it has username password text box and a submit button. since I don't have the csrftoken on my JavaScript server, I chose to disable csrf token instead. In "urls.py", the url patterns

```
url(r'^login/$', csrf_exempt(login_view), name='login_view')
```

My understanding is this will exempt the login page from csrf authentication? But what I need to be able to login using post,

```
$.post({
  url:"https://mayan/authentication/login/",
  data:"username=admin&password=mypassword&next=/",
});
```

Am I posting wrong? or am I exempting csrf wrongly? Because I kept receiving a http status code 403 Forbidden.

Edit:

In my login_view, it calls a method login from another view, and the login method also calls other functions. do I need to add "@csrf_exempt" before "def login" or do I need to add it to every function? will adding csrf_exempt to login method be sufficient?